# While doing a transition between two screens how to tell the source widget we are in a transition?

Tags: flutter, transition

From my source widget which displays an autoplay fullscreen video, I'd like to slide to the user's profile on a pan gesture.

My source widget starts playing the video from the initState(), and before I push my profile screen, I pause the video so the sound is muted and the streaming stopped.

But When I slide it, the video is restarted as the `initState()` is actually resumed (I don't understand why the widget is restarted though).

If I simply push my profile screen, it works, no problem, the video is not resumed.

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(
  destination));
```

See my code as follows.

From my pan gesture I do that:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  SlideInOutTransition(oldScreen: widget, newScreen: destination));
```

My slider is as follows:

```dart
class SlideInOutTransition extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget oldScreen;
  final Widget newScreen;
  SlideInOutTransition({required this.oldScreen, required this.newScreen})
      : super(
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) =>
              newScreen,
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) =>
              Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              SlideTransition(
                position: Tween<Offset>(
                  begin: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                  end: const Offset(-1.0, 0.0),
                ).animate(animation),
                child: oldScreen,
              ),
              SlideTransition(
                position: Tween<Offset>(
                  begin: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),
                  end: Offset.zero,
                ).animate(animation),
                child: newScreen,
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
}
```

So my objective is to keep the transition, but find a way for the video not to be resumed from the iniState().

Q1) Why is it so that my current source widget is restarted?
Q2) How to pass the information so that I would not start the video when we are transitioning?

Of course if you think of another better way to to that, I take it :) !